# I have an SSL but the pages are not showing lock signs which I need for my order page

Tags: html, security, ssl, browser

I have an old site I am just about well enough (broken arm + cancer) to start working on again and I have already moved it to another server OVH and added an SSL/TLS certificate to it.

However in Chrome when I visit any page on the site, especially  https://www.strictly-software.com/plugins/order.asp it shows either (don't know why refreshes would change it but they do sometimes) the insecure sign with the red line through the https:// part of the URL in the address bar or an information circle.

In Firefox however I get a secure lock sign. It maybe some add-on I have used like a popup blocker or something but I am at a loss to find out what is causing these insecure signs to appear when I need locks, especially on the order page

This morning I spent hours going through loads of JavaScript and CSS (background:http://blah.jpg) etc and changing it so it is local and cannot be changed remotely as well as making any http references into src="//" or href="//" etc.

I thought it must be one of the images on the "add this" pop up but cannot see anything in their code. Then I thought the Twitter scroller might be showing images from http destinations but Twitter wraps them all in their own URL format.

Does anyone know from looking at the generated source code what is making the page insecure?

Surely there should be a list somewhere in the browser that shows what content isn't secure and offers you to load or not load it? I know the information icon lets you load or not lot Flash, images or JavaScript but do you know of how I can find out what content isn't secure on these pages without asking visitors?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't reproduce this in Chromium; the padlock is green. Doesn't the Network or Console tab in the inspector show anything?

Comment: Welcome back. There are a couple of things you can enhance in security, as mentioned by SSLLabs ( https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.strictly-software.com )

Comment: is this one local data="//bin.clearspring.com/at/v/1/button1.6.swf" ?

Comment: Weird it only happens to me in Chrome, FF is okay. I bet it is the bookmark scriptlet I made for my bookmark bar that gives you Real Generated Source Code with one click OR it could be the Chrome version of Web Dev Toolbar that does more like turn passwords into clear text or clear cookies. I bet that gets loaded in with the page somehow.